# When is the Nilradical sequence of a ring split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and denote by $N_R$ the nilradical of $R$. When is the sequence of $R$-modules

$0 \to N_R \to R \to R_{\text{red}}\to 0$

split, i.e. $R\cong N_R\oplus R_{\text{red}}$? The ring I am interested in is not necessarily semisimple, however it is local and noetherian.

Is there a general criterion when an ideal yields such a split exact sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the radical is zero, it does.

Otherwise, never.

It can’t ever split because the nilradical is a [superfluous submodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension), meaning it cannot be complemented by a proper submodule.

For the same reason, the Jacobson radical can’t split out as an $R$ submodule (except in the case where it is zero.)

Another way to see it: the thing splitting out  has to contain a nontrivial idempotent, and it clearly cannot for the nilradical (or Jacobson radical either.)